# How can I convert this linq to bool

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, inventory

How to convert a query to bool?
I used the "ALL (x => x)" but did not give the answer I needed.

Code Line

```
checkItemInventory.Where(x => listCost.Contains(x.Id));
```

In this case, the `listcost` would have `2` items, I needed to check if the `checkItemInventory` has these `2` items.

Comment: I apologize for any error or poor explanation.
I'm from Brazil and my English is not the best.

In case it would be two lists, I need to check if the list (checkItemInventory), contains the list items (listCost).

What I need in case is this, if I have the amount or more it returns true, if I do not have it returns false.

Comment: I implemented it, but apparently it keeps returning true, even without any item in the inventory.

Comment: I put the BuildItem script and an image, to try to illustrate what is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"All items in the inventory have an id that present in listcost". listCost needs to have the same number of items as inventory (assuming Id is unique) possibly more, to stand a chance of returning true

```
checkItemInventory.All(x => listCost.Contains(x.Id))
```

"At least one item in the inventory has an id that is also in listCost". Listcost could minimally have only one id in it, to stand a chance of returning true

```
checkItemInventory.Any(x => listCost.Contains(x.Id))
```

As you can see, neither of these are what you want as you seem to be saying you want to check whether every item in listcost is also present in the inventory. This is like the top code, but the other way round ("all items in listCost are present in inventory" vs "all items in inventory are present in listcost"

I think I'd make a dictionary out of the inventory first, unless it's already something that supports a fast lookup:

```
var d = checkItemInventory.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Id }).ToDictionary();
var boolResult = listCost.All(lc => d.ContainsKey(lc));
```

If inventory is small, you could use this approach:

```
listCost.All(lc => checkItemInventory.Any(cii => cii.Id == lc));
```

Just be mindful that internally it might do something like:

```
bool all = true;
foreach(lc in listCost){
  bool found = false;
  foreach(cci in checkItemInventory)
    if(lc == cci.Id){
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  all &= found;
  if(!all)
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Which is a lot of repeated comparisons (for every item in listCost, the whole inventory is scanned), could be slow

#### Edit

I asked for clarification of how you store your inventory and your costs of building items. Here's one assumption I made, and how a solutio based on it might work:

Assuming your inventory has the kind of item and a count saying how many of that item the player is carrying:

```
class InventoryItem{
  int ItemKindId { get; set;}
  int CountOf { get; set; }
}

player.Inventory.Add(new InventoryItem() { 
  ItemKindId = Constants.WOOD, //1
  CountOf = 10 //holding 10 items of wood
};
player.Inventory.Add(new InventoryItem() { 
  ItemKindId = Constants.STONE, //2
  CountOf = 5 //holding 5 items of stone
};
```

Assuming you have a Recipe for making e.g. an axe, it needs 1 wood and 2 stone, but it lists them in simple order:

```
int[] axeRecipe = new int[] { Constants.WOOD, Constants.STONE, Constants.STONE };
```

Might be easiest to group the recipe:

```
var recipe = axeRecipe.GroupBy(item => item)

/*
  now we have a grouping of the recipe[item].Key as the material and a
  recipe[item].Count() of how much. The group is like a dictionary:

  recipe[Constants.WOOD] = new List<int>{ Constants.WOOD };
  recipe[Constants.STONE] = new List<int>{ Constants.STONE, Constants.STONE, };
  A group item has a Key and a list of objects that have that key
  Because my recipe was simply ints, the Key is the same number as all the 
  items in the list
*/

//for all items in the recipe
grp.All(groupItem =>
  //does the player inventory contain any item
  playerInventory.Any(inventoryItem => 
    //where the material kind is the same as the recipe key (material)
    inventoryItem.ItemKindId == groupItem.Key &&
    //and the count they have of it, is enough to make the recipe
    inventoryItem.CountOf >= groupItem.Count()
);
```

You can of course reduce this to a single line if you want: `axeRecipe.GroupBy(...).All(...)`

Comment: In this case the listcost would have 2 items, I needed to check if the inventory has these 2 items.

Comment: Thank you very much, I apologize again because my English is very basic, so I'll spare you a few words to avoid complications.
Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: In case I have in the listcost more than 1 item with the same id, for example listcost having 2 stones and 1 wood?

Comment: Probably best if you give some example that lets me link it to a real-world problem, like "i'm writing a game and the player can pick things up off the ground but they can only use them if they have ever bought them before.. So I have a checkItemInventory which is a list of things the player has bought before and a listCost which is things the player picked up. So i want to know if the player can use all of the things he is currently holding so I can color my USE button green, or RED if any one of the things cannot be used"

Comment: I apologize for not explaining very well.

checkItemInventory = List of items that the player picked up on the floor.
listCost = The list of items needed for the player to craft a new item.

What I need to do = Check if the list (checkItemInventory) has the items that are being passed in the listCost.

Comment: I put the BuildItem script and an image, to try to illustrate what is needed.

Comment: Can you please edit your question so it has a better description of what the inventory has in it, what the objects are like, and also what is in itemtoslot.cost, what those objects look like

Comment: I added some code based on an assumption; have a go at adjusting it to your app

Comment: I tried again, but I curled up.
I'll post the inventory and slots script.

Comment: I left there all the scripts, in case I also took advantage of it and left the script of the items, in case I did not exactly define a script for each item, they are copies of the script itself and in their prefabs I change the name, id and others.

Comment: I took and I put an image of how I create an item and its properties.

Comment: I updated the checkInventory () method, I used its logic and now it works partially, it counts the items, but there is only one problem. In case to build the shovel he needs 2 stones and wood, but however he put 2 woods and 1 stone also goes.

Comment: This code `return listCost.All(gp => inventoryItems.Any(iI => iI.Id == gp.Key && inventoryItems.Count > gp.Count()));` is "if the material matches and the count of the entire inventory is greater than the number of material needed". What you want is "if the material matches and the count of the material is greater or equal".. so `return listCost.All(gp => inventoryItems.Any(iI => iI.Id == gp.Key && iI.Count >= gp.Count()));` .. I changed `inventoryItems.Count` , to `iI.Count` (and I changed `>` to `>=`)

Comment: SUCCESS, THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP, I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO THANK. I ONLY NEED TO GROUP THE INVENTORY ITEMS ON A VARIABLE, BUT IT IS WORKING PERFECTLY. THANK YOU VERY MUCH. :)

Final Code

        var inventoryItems = buildItems.inventory.slot.Where(x => x.itemToSlot != null).SelectMany(x => x.itemToSlot.amountItem).GroupBy(x => x.Id);

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't respond earlier, was away from keyboard teaching a lesson.. Glad you got it sorted! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could map the `listCost` to a list of `int` and then use `Except()` and `Any()` to check whether all items are contained:

```
bool containsAll = !listCost.Select(x => x.Id).Except(checkItemInventory).Any();
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you all for the effort and dedication.
Thank you so much.
:)

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE]**

You are telling us the following:

> How to convert a query to bool? I used the "ALL (x => x)" but did not give the answer I needed.
>
> `checkItemInventory.Where(x => listCost.Contains(x.Id));`
>
> In this case, the listcost would have 2 items, I needed to check if
>   the checkItemInventory has these 2 items.

if you need to check if there is any result then you can use:

```
bool hasItems = checkItemInventory.Where(x => listCost.Contains(x.Id)).Any();
```

if you need to count the result you can use

```
 checkItemInventory.Where(x => listCost.Contains(x.Id)).Count();
```

Comment: Count can be optimised to Any if all you care about is count > 0

Comment: Sorry I did not understand. :(

Comment: Thank you, thank you all for the effort and dedication.
Thank you so much.
:)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Join` to create a method based Linq query and use the results to check if the length of the list is greater than 0. Then turn that into a boolean.

```
var query = checkItemInventory.Join(listCost,
                                    inventory => inventory.Id,
                                    cost => cost.Id,
                                    (inventory, cost) => new { id = inventory.Id });

var count = query.ToList().Count();
var b = (count > 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you all for the effort and dedication.
Thank you so much.
:)

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, `listCost` can have **less** elements than `checkItemInventory`. You want to check that all elements in listCost have a corresponding element in checkItemInventory. Correct? If yes, try this:

```
listCost.All(x => checkItemInventory.Contains(x));
```

I don't know the type of these lists, so you might need to use `x.id` in some places

Comment: listCost would be the list of items needed for the player to create the item, and checkItemInventory would be the list of items that the player has.
In this case the listCost script would be a slot with the shovel item, in that shovel item it would have 2 attached items that would be a stone and 1 wood.
If the player has these 2 items or more in his inventory he can do it.